# How to avoid cycle or loop in path Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a problem when i use the path variables.

For example my hierarchy looks like

```
A-[Knows]-> B   
B-[Knows]-> C  
C-[Knows]-> D  
D-[Knows]-> E  
C-[Knows]-> F  
F-[Knows]-> G  
G-[Knows]-> B
```

My query is `MATCH p = (x)<-[Knows*]->(y) Return p`

The relation direction have to be bidirectional. Toy problem is like A,B but in real application, i don't know direction of relations.

So there is a cycle and loop. The path start to find from A to C. But after finding C, next steps, cycle is happened.

How to avoid the loop or how to ignore it, how to remove from actual path or how to stop when the path end in B. I don't need to find second B to C.

Expected result :

```
A->B->C->D->E
A->B->C->F->G->B  // that is enough. The query must be stopped.
```

Actual result :

```
A->B->C->D->E
A->B->C->F->G->B->C->F->G->B..... loop trouble.
```

Comment: Just a quick note, in your examples, `Knows` is the variable for the var-length relationship...it isn't the relationship type. A relationship type in Cypher is always prefixed with a `:`. You probably meant to use `MATCH p = (x)<-[:Knows*]->(y) Return p`. If you also want a variable on the var-length relationship, the variable will go before the `:`

Comment: Are you searching for all reachable nodes from A using any path? It's not quite clear to me if you know your end node, or if you're just looking to keep traversing and just want distinct nodes.

Answer (score 5):

How can we verify that the path includes a cycle?

A simple way in clear cypher it is to count the number of unique nodes of the path and compare it with the path length increased by one:

```
MATCH path = (x)-[:KNOWS*]-(y)
  UNWIND NODES(path) AS n
    WITH path, 
         SIZE(COLLECT(DISTINCT n)) AS testLength 
    WHERE testLength = LENGTH(path) + 1
RETURN path
```

You can simplify the query using the collection functions from the [`APOC library`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions).

For example:

```
MATCH path = (x)-[:KNOWS*]-(y)
      WHERE SIZE(apoc.coll.toSet(NODES(path))) > LENGTH(path) + 1
RETURN path
```

Or we can simplify:

```
MATCH path = (x)-[:KNOWS*]-(y) 
      WHERE apoc.coll.duplicates(NODES(path)) = []
RETURN path
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, to avoid loops, cypher has the following mecanism : in a pattern, you can only traverse once a relationship.

The problem of your query is that you are searching all the paths between all your nodes (that's why it takes some times).

If you only want to search the shortespath between two node, you can use the cypher's shortespath function : `MATCH p = shortestpath((x)-[Knows*]-(y)) RETURN p`.

Moreover, if you now the ending node, you should tell it to cypher :

```
MATCH p = shortestpath((x)-[Knows*]-(y)) 
WHERE x.name = 'A' AND y.name = 'B'
RETURN p
```

Cheers

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your answer.                               
But one of the requirements is that there can be more than two relationship in my pattern. So when i want to use shortest path, it gives error.

The other problem is that  your example return A->B that is the shortest path. 
So it is not the solution for me. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that would get at your desired result.

A few things to note.  I started with node A rather than apply the pattern across the entire graph. In order to get your desired result with cypher I queried the relationship `KNOWS` as directed. If you remove the direction then you get more results which I am not sure are incorrect. Anyways, you can decide for yourself.

The query finds all of the paths and then factors out the ones that are included in the longest distinct paths.

First I started with a little data...

```
CREATE (A:Person {name: 'A'})
CREATE (B:Person {name: 'B'})
CREATE (C:Person {name: 'C'})
CREATE (D:Person {name: 'D'})
CREATE (E:Person {name: 'E'})
CREATE (F:Person {name: 'F'})
CREATE (G:Person {name: 'G'})
CREATE (A)-[:KNOWS]->(B)
CREATE (B)-[:KNOWS]->(C)   
CREATE (C)-[:KNOWS]->(D)  
CREATE (D)-[:KNOWS]->(E)  
CREATE (C)-[:KNOWS]->(F)  
CREATE (F)-[:KNOWS]->(G)  
CREATE (G)-[:KNOWS]->(B)
RETURN *
```

Here is the query

```
// find all the variable length paths starting with A
MATCH path = (x:Person)-[:KNOWS*]->(y:Person)
WHERE x.name = 'A'

// collect the paths and collect the paths excluding the last node
WITH COLLECT(path) AS paths,
     COLLECT(DISTINCT nodes(path)[0..size(nodes(path))-1]) AS all_but_last_nodes_of_paths

// filter the paths out that are already included (i.e. shorter ones)
WITH [p IN paths WHERE NOT nodes(p) IN all_but_last_nodes_of_paths] AS paths_to_keep

// return each path to keep
UNWIND paths_to_keep AS path
WITH reduce(path_txt = "", n in nodes(path) | path_txt + n.name + "->") AS path_txt
RETURN left(path_txt,size(path_txt)-2) AS path_txt
```

Here is the same query solved also with APOC instead of just cypher using expandConfig. Note that it also relies on specifying the direction when querying to get your desired result set.

```
MATCH (x:Person)
WHERE x.name = 'A'
WITH x
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(x, {
                                relationshipFilter:'KNOWS>',
                                labelFilter:'+Person',
                                uniqueness: 'RELATIONSHIP_PATH'
                           } ) YIELD path AS path
WITH COLLECT(path) AS paths,
     COLLECT(DISTINCT nodes(path)[0..size(nodes(path))-1]) AS all_but_last_nodes_of_paths
WITH [p IN paths WHERE NOT nodes(p) IN all_but_last_nodes_of_paths] AS paths_to_keep
UNWIND paths_to_keep AS path
WITH reduce(path_txt = "", n in nodes(path) | path_txt + n.name + "->") AS path_txt
RETURN left(path_txt,size(path_txt)-2) AS path_txt
```